# why is nginx timeout-ing?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

Here is my timeout related nginx conf  :

```
http {

...

proxy_read_timeout 300;
proxy_connect_timeout 300;
proxy_send_timeout 300;

...

}
```

and my reverse proxy setup :

```
upstream node {
        server 127.0.0.1:2200;
}

server {
  listen 80;
 
  location / {
        proxy_pass http://node;
    }
}
```

I am posting a query to my webserver and nginx times out after 1 minute with the following message :

> 2021/07/16 14:35:42 [error] 881124#881124: *14744 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.68.144.214, server: , request: "POST /photos/download_photos HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:2200/photos/download_photos", host: "myhost.com", referrer: "https://myhost.com/"

Output of `sudo nginx -T` :

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        client_max_body_size 100m;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/reverse-proxy:
upstream node {
        server 127.0.0.1:2200;
}


server {
  listen 80;
 # server_name tools.tryandreview.com;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://node;
    }
}
```

Why is nginx not taking my setting into account ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Are you sure your node application is returning a response in five minutes?

Comment: thank you for replying. Yes I am.

Comment: And in any case it times out after 1 minute.

Comment: `ETIMEDOUT` or Error #110 is thrown when [client can't connect on a socket after a certain amount of time](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html#ERRORS). are you sure your node is listening on `127.0.0.1:2200`? try `curl`-ing to your node app.

Comment: It does work fine for queries that don't take more than a minute so I'm certain node is listening.

Comment: Could it have something to do with user authorization ie sudo vs non sudo ? I always have to use sudo to edit conf and/or print nginx -T etc.

Comment: I think you missed one timeout  `send_timeout 300s;`

Comment: For Duplicity i needed to use  `proxy_connect_timeout 600; proxy_send_timeout 600; proxy_read_timeout 600; send_timeout 600;` it might also a good idea to use memcached to cache some querys, if you like to do so  `set $memcached_key "$uri?$args"; memcached_pass 127.0.0.1:11211;` would ba a good option to solve such repsonse issues

Comment: i am also found a other configuration perl of nginx `client_header_timeout 3600; client_body_timeout 3600; fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;`

Comment: [`proxy_connect_timeout`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_connect_timeout) does have a hard limit of 75s, but if shorter queries are fine, then `connect` phase should be fine, `read` phase would be having problems. try running with `error_log debug`, and see what comes out before it timed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one timeout that is missing

```
send_timeout 300s;
```